# How can i enter with test accounts to Paypal sandbox in android?

Tags: android, api, paypal

Hi i am developing a shopping application with payment system as Pappal in Android.

But i have problem with using sandbox.Because i can't control or enter with sandbox i am using this tutorial [**Paypal Android Tutorial**](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf) and i couldn't.

Paypal application ID = "APP-80W284485P519543T" is my using. But i dont know how can enter with user.Can you help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need valid PayPal app id for sandbox environment. You can use any string for this field.

```
// The PayPal server to be used - ENV_SANDBOX, ENV_NONE or ENV_LIVE
int PAYPAL_SERVER = PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX;
```

Please read this document carefully. There is everything you need to know about this library.

```
PayPal ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), "APP-
80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
```

If you need user - you should register at developer.paypal.com and create several test users.

Comment: actually i create some user but i couldnt connect to my own sandbox this id is general paypal id

Comment: AppID - it could be any string for sandbox. it doesnt matter. 
What do you mean under 'couldnt connect' ? you have connection error ?

Comment: Firstly i need to access my own sandbox users', i have to change app id? Secondly i tried any string but couldnt enter. I must enter for check payment is come true or not.

Comment: 1. To access sandbox users - see https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf

2. You need to draw paypal checkout button on your view. Did you manage doing this ?

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko : Can I create test users programatically?